# IBM Bluemix customizing mobile app map with geoanalytics

Tags: mobile, maps, ibm-cloud, iot

### Heading

I am new to use IBM Bluemix. I wish to create an application which tracks vehicles. A region on map will be divided into 4 sub regions and each sub region will have five vehicles. Whenever, the vehicles leaves its region, the manager will be notified. I know that it can be done by using IOT and geoanalytics. Is there anyway I can use geo analytics with my mobile application (which i have built using IBM mobile services). If so how? If no, is there any other possible way to do the required i.e. breaking region into sub regions. Any link or comment will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the following links suitable for your requirement?
[Build a connected-car IoT app with Geospatial Analytics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-connectedcar-app/index.html)
[Monitor mobile devices with the Geospatial Analytics service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-monitordevices-app/index.html?ca=drs-)